# androidx SwitchPreferenceCompat on Toolbar

Tags: android, androidx

I want to use SwitchPreferenceCompat on toolbar,
How Can I do that?
Thank you very much.

my codes like that:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

            final SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("sync");
            if(switchPreference != null){
                switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        boolean isOn = (Boolean) newValue;

                        SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) preference;

                        switchPreference.setChecked(isOn);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml/root_preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="sync" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Is it possible?
I need your help
Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Toolbar is just another ViewGroup, so you can just add a SwitchCompat inside your Toolbar in your layout.xml

Comment: @DarShan Can you give me an example, I'm new on java.